# Не правильный URI для возврата

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, upload, uri

Клиент отправляет на сервер картинку. На сервере в конфиге прописан каталог для сохранения изображения:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.location=C:/images
```

Код сильно сокращен ( оставил основное ), здесь формируется новое имя для картинки и она сохраняется в каталог из конфига.

```
 public URI uploadImage(MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        String originalFilename = image.getOriginalFilename();
        String extension = getExtension(originalFilename);
        File file = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + extension);
        image.transferTo(file);
        return file.toURI();
    }
```

Пытаюсь вернуть **URI** картинки мне возвращает: **путь проекта + название картинки**, а должно быть путь из **конфига + название картинки**.

Нужна ваша помощь как исправить?

Comment: Прочитать значение из конфига и передать в new File, как первый параметр

Comment: @Sergi а как это сделать?)

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

Comment: @Sergi благодарю , сделал бин через @PropertySource("classpath:global.properties")

Comment: @Sergi напишите ответ, я его приму

Comment: ОК, рад что помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте значение из конфига (см. https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/) и передайте в new File, как первый параметр.